# IPN paypal it not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a problem. In January the code for PayPal IPN was working, and in February is stopped working. What could it change?
Here is the code

```html
<?php
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL)
     $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    else
     $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    
  $adres = "jankowski095@gmail.com";
$tytul = "Zakupiono przedmiot";
$wiadomosc = "Zakupiono "; 
mail($adres, $tytul, $wiadomosc);
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
  $adres = "jankowski095@gmail.com";
$tytul = "Tytuł wiadomoścasdi no";
$wiadomosc = "IPN nie działa.";
mail($adres, $tytul, $wiadomosc);
  }
?>
```

I do not know why it stopped working from PayPal I did not get any notification of changes in the software. Help me please

Comment: Maybe you changed your account settings or the IPN code number changed not the code.

Comment: Their code for me also, unfortunately, does not work